# An upper bound and simplification for expression

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I would like to find the upper bound (or simplification) of this expression:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} a^{j+i} {j+i \choose i}{n+1\choose j}{n \choose i}/{2n+1 \choose j+i}$$ where $0<a<1$ is constant.

Please help me to solve it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Recently you asked a lot of similar questions, about finding or bounding the peculiar sum $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a^{j+i} f(i,j)$$ where $f(i,j)$ is a product of binomial coefficients. May I dare to ask you why? Just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write our sum in the more symmetric fashion:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i<j}a^{i+j}\frac{\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n+1}{j}}{\binom{2n+2}{i+j}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{j-i}{2n+2-(i+j)}\right)$$
and see that it is bounded by the symmetric one:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i<j}a^{i+j}\frac{\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n+1}{j}}{\binom{2n+2}{i+j}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{n+1}{2n+2-(i+j)}\right)$$
that can be bounded by:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{a^k}{\binom{2n+2}{k}}\left(1+\frac{n+1}{2n+2-k}\right)\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n+2}{k}$$
that can be bounded by:
$$\frac{1}{2(1-a)}+\frac{(n+1)a^{2n+2}}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{a^{-k}}{k}$$
that can be bounded by:
$$\frac{1}{2(1-a)}+\frac{n+1}{2}a\, H_{2n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks Jack.
I have some misunderstanding:
Line 1=>line 2: since $1\le j-i\le n+1$?
Line 2=>line 3: is that ${n+1\choose i}{n+1 \choose j}\le 1/2{2n+2 \choose i+j}$? or strictly less than?
Line 4: I don't know how you can obtain this. Is it related to previous problem? Please explain me more :( 
Thanks again

Comment: Line 1 to Line 2: yes, $j-i\leq n+1$. Line 2 to Line 3: no, it follows from the Chu-Vandermonde identity $$\sum_{i+j=k}\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n+1}{j}=\binom{2n+2}{k}$$ and from the fact that you are not summing on the whole set of positive integers such that $i+j=k$.

Comment: And how about line 3 to line 4?

Comment: Cancel out the term $\binom{2n+2}{k}$, detach the part that is the partial sum of a geometric series. For the remaining piece, exchange $k$ with $2n+2-k$ in order to have a partial sum of the Taylor series of $-\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer?
In addition, is there any mistake in the last line with  $log(1-1/a)$ for $0<a<1$? since $1-1/a>0$ iff $a>1$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, the one on the right of the fourth line is obviously the truncated Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$, but the equality does not hold when $x>1$, obviously.

Comment: @Alex: I just edited the post.

Comment: $H_{2n+1}$: is it Harmonic number?

I have a question: this bound is always $<1$? since this homework needs the upper bound $<1$

Comment: Could you please explain me more about the step: line 3 to line 4?